# How can I receive the sent data in mongoose?

Tags: c++, c, mongoose

I am using mongoose.c and I have written a program, in order to receive POST requests. The scenario is that mongoose should receive JSON and save it to a file `config.conf`:

In order to manage that, I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Mongoose/Mongoose.h"

static void saveToFile(std::string fileName, std::string text)
{
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "wb");

    fwrite(text.c_str(), sizeof(text[0]), sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0]), file);

    fclose(file);
}

static void ev_handler_to_Receive_file(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *ev_data)
{
    char buff[65536];

    if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST)
    {
        struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data;

        std::string uri = hm->uri.p;

        // We have received an HTTP request. Parsed request is contained in `hm`.
        // Send HTTP reply to the client which shows full original request.

        if (strncmp(hm->method.p, "POST", hm->method.len) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "POST DETECTED" << std::endl;
            if (std::string::npos != uri.find("/config"))
            {
                std::cout << "#config# DETECTED" << std::endl;
                //Read post data
                memcpy(buff, hm->body.p, hm->body.len);
                std::string data (buff);

                std::cout << buff << std::endl;

                saveToFile("config.conf", buff);
            }
        }

        mg_send_head(nc, 200, hm->message.len, "Content-Type: text/plain");
        mg_printf(nc, "%.*s", (int)hm->message.len, hm->message.p);
      }
}

void initializeServer()
{
    int numberOfPolls = 1;
    struct mg_mgr mongooseEventManager;

    struct mg_connection *mongooseConnection;

    // Start Web Server
    mg_mgr_init(&mongooseEventManager, NULL);

    mongooseConnection = mg_bind(&mongooseEventManager, "8000", ev_handler_to_Receive_file);

    mg_set_protocol_http_websocket(mongooseConnection);

    while(true)
    {
        printf("POLL[%i]\n", numberOfPolls);
        mg_mgr_poll(&mongooseEventManager, 500);
        numberOfPolls++;
    }

    mg_mgr_free(&mongooseEventManager);
}

int main()
{
    initializeServer();

    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine for short JSON files, but in case the JSON file is larger than approximately 20 charachter, I loose the rest of the JSON text.

for example, in case I send the folowing JSON file, everything works fine:

```
{
   TEST:true
}
```

a config.conf file is created and contains the JSON text.

On the other hand, in case I send for example the following JSON file:

```
{
   TEST:true,
   TEST2:false,
   TEST3:false
}
```

The generated file contains the following text:

```
{
   TEST:true,
   TEST2:false,
```

In case anybody knows how to fix this problem, I would really appreciate any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to copying a char* to std::string and the way we write the content to the file.

```
memcpy(buff, hm->body.p, hm->body.len);
std::string data (buff);

std::cout << buff << std::endl;

saveToFile("config.conf", buff);
```

You can convert this pointer using std::string constructor like below

```
std::cout << "#config# DETECTED" << std::endl;
std::string data(hm->body.p, hm->body.len);
saveToFile("config.conf", data);
```

change your SaveToFile() like below

```
static void saveToFile(std::string& fileName, std::string& text)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "wb");
    fwrite(text.c_str(), sizeof(text[0]), text.size(), file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

I tried this code and working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code works fine, but I omitted to change the signature of saveToFile method, because the code could not be compiled.